# Maximizing $\infty$-norm with inequality constraint on $2$-norm

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, singular-values

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2553071/maximization-of-infinity-norm-with-2-norm-constraint) question asks about

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\max_{\mathbf x \in \mathbb C^n} && \|\mathbf B\mathbf x\|_{\infty} \\
&\ \ \text{s.t.} && \|\mathbf x\|_2\leq 1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

and I understand the answer. Is there a better way to compute it than exhaustively computing the $2$-norm of every row of $\mathbf{B}$? Especially the case where $\mathbf{B}$ is too large to form explicitly and $\mathbf{Bx}$ is implemented with a function. (It can also be assumed that $\mathbf{B}^\mathrm{H} \mathbf{y}$ is computable with a function.)

I believe the difficulty is that the cost function is differentiable but not smooth, so something along the lines of a projected gradient is not guaranteed to work. I believe that proximal gradient algorithms are used to minimize problems of this form. However, it is not clear to me how to apply that here where we are maximizing.

Comment: Don't you mean $Bx$ can be computed by  function, or elements of $B$ can be computed by a function. If $B$ is computed by a function, then obviously it is not too large to be formed

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Hopefully the question is more accurately worded now.

Answer (score 0):

Better in what sense? From a computational complexity perspective, you cannot do better as that computation essentially is no more work than reading/looking at every element of $B$, which you would have to do regardless (unless you are talking massive size and/or randomized methods)

Comment: $\mathbf{B}$ is not explicitly formed due its size; rather, it is implemented with a function. I can compute its gradient easy enough and have implemented an iterative projected gradient approximation to the solution. The problem with this, I believe, is that the function is differentiable but not smooth, so gradient-based methods are not guaranteed to work. My understanding is that proxmial-gradient methods are used for minimizing problems like this, but it's not clear to me how to apply that to this situation where are want to maximize.

Comment: Then you should add that to the question, as it is essential.